# Translation of: 代理人のご到着かな?

Tags: grammar

In the subtitles for the first episode of Code Geass, a character asks:

> 代理人のご到着かな

Maybe there is a grammer point that I don't understand, but shouldnt this be:

> 代理人のが到着かな

Meaning something like: as for 代理人 (the substitute), 到着 (the arrival) is here, isn't it?

instead though there is a ご where I expect a が. Is this slang maybe? Or a grammer point I don't know?

Comment: In Japanese you often see a noun phrase functioning as a self-sufficient, semantically complete sentence. Such noun phrases often occur as "A's B"/"B of A".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

の here is the possessive marker, not the nominalizer; ご is an honorific.
かな adds the sense of wondering.

> 代理人のご到着かな

> I wonder whether is that the arrival of the representative.

代理人 must be someone important or esteemed or who should be respected, thus the use of the honorific: ご到着

Without further context, it's a bit more difficult to say much more.

代理人のが到着かな doesn't make any sense grammatically.  If you wanted to make
代理人 the subject of a verb, they could have said

> 代理人が到着したかな

> I wonder did the representative arrive?

You can't use the honorific prefix here.

I'm not entirely sure how to form a suitable honorific here.  I'm used to hearing

> まもなく到着いたします

But that would not be suitable here since いたす is humble.  (You hear this expression over the loud speaker in the train station for example.)

I suppose it might be

> ご到着になりました

resulting in

> 代理人がご到着になりましたかな

Some feedback on this last point might be nice.  Keigo is not my forte.  I understand it usually when I hear it (assuming it's not over the top), but it's passive knowledge, not active for me.